# What is the relation of Zin with Hyatie in Tekken?

Tags: anime, tekken

I have seen two movies with a similar name, Tekken. One was from hollywood and the other was a cartoon/anime. I just wanted to know the relation between Hyatie and Zin because between the two there were different identities in the movies described.

Comment: Who are these people you speak of (Do you mean Jin Kazama and Heihachi Mishima)? Which "Tekken" movies/cartoon/anime do you refer to (what year did they come out)? Also what does any of this have to do with "red faction?" Please give sufficient clarification.

Comment: yes,I am talking about the two of them.I am talking about both the hollywood movie as well as anime series.

Comment: at least give me an appropriate answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the 2010 live-action film:

From Kazuya Mishima's [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuya_Mishima):

> In the 2010 live-action film Tekken, (...) Kazuya is Heihachi's right-hand man in Tekken Corporation, wishing to take over his father's company.

So Kazuya is Heihachi's son. Considering Jin Kazama's [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_Kazama):

> In the 2010 live-action film Tekken, (...) he is (...) the illegitimate son of Kazuya.

This means, in the year 2000 Tekken live action movie, Jin is Heihachi's grandson.

---

The same should also be true for the anime version, as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekken%3a_The_Motion_Picture) reads:

> Kazuya (..) gives into his power again and overpowers his father brutally.

Which means Kazuya is Heihachi's son again.
I can't really prove that she has a child with Kazuya in the anime, but:

> Sometime later, Jun is seen knitting in a wood. Her young son, Jin appears.

Which means Jin is Jun's son, who had a relationship with Heihachi's son.

So I guess it's not that much of a stretch to assume that Jin is Heihachi's grandson.